# Deployment issue with Azure Emulator

Tags: c#, deployment, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to run a local instance of an Azure Worker Role for debugging and testing, but for some reason, my Role will not deploy to the Emulator locally, it is saying, "The compute emulator had a error: Found too many .csdef files.."

The problem is, I checked the project directory, and there is only one csdef file...

I have already built the file as required with CSPack, and my CSRun command looks like this:

csrun.exe /run:C:\ODA
T\WorkerRole\WorkerRole;C:\ODAT\WorkerRole\WorkerRole\
ServiceDefinition.csdef

And this is being ran at the following director: C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would u please show your WorkerRole directory structure? Looking that I can guess what do u have so I can suggest how to use CSRUN properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the cscfg file not the csdef and use the .csx directory for the emulator.

csrun C:\ODAT\WorkerRole\WorkerRole.csx C:\ODAT\WorkerRole\WorkerRole.cscfg

If you don't have a .cscfg file you can have cspack create it for you by specifying the /generateConfigurationFile:ServiceConfiguration.cscfg